# CentOS 7 no terminal on boot

Tags: centos, boot, hang

I have rebuilt my CentOS 7 server and on restart, the boot screen locks up, yet I can remote in to the server just fine as through it has fully booted.

Restarting and looking at the boot messages, the last message is:

```
[   OK   ] Stopped dracut pre-pivot and cleanup hook
```

How can I:

a) fix the boot process?

or

b) study the boot process to see what is hanging?

One hint is that the BIOS reported it had been reset, however I look at its settings and the date and time are correct, and all other settings look good. I may have touched a reset jumper on the motherboard inadvertently.

**More Information:**

While the screen update stalls after the message above, after remoting into the system, the `/var/log/boot.log` file contains the remainder of the boot process. This could point to a graphics issue?

Comment: What does the boot log and dmesg say when you log in remotely?

Comment: I have updated the question with the boot log information you asked for. Interesting, seems like the boot is fine but the graphics is stalling.

Comment: Regarding closure, while it is a rare scenario, it could easily be reproduced by those using an external graphics card. I suspect the site is here to service repeatable issues, no matter their rarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the onboard graphics had been switched on in the BIOS reset. This meant that for whatever reason, the PCIe graphics card would receive graphical updates up to a point during the boot, then hang on the last update, while the onboard graphics continued to run.

Disabling the onboard graphics in the BIOS has fixed my issue.